# Is there a function for finding multiplicative inverse of int in the ring Z/nZ?

Tags: go

I know of the function `math/big.ModInverse`, which I've used succesfully when handling `*big.Int`s. But now I'm looking for a corresponding function for `int`.

Is there such a function? I scrolled through [the `math` documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/math/) without finding anything.

Or is the best way to convert to `*big.Int` and use `ModInverse`?

Comment: You mean `1 / x`? It's just a simple division. Why do you need a function for it?

Comment: `ModInverse` finds the inverse in the ring ℤ/nℤ, which isn't equivalent to `1 / x`. I probably should emphasize that.

Comment: "Is there such a function?" No, but porting math/big.Int.ModInverse to ints should be pretty simple if you have a working GCD.

Comment: Create one yourself maybe

Comment: It's just a few lines of code: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Modular_integers